# When boolean add(E element) method of linked list in java return false

Tags: java, collections

When boolean add(E element) method of linked list in java return false?

I have investigated LinkedList Implementation and found boolean add(E element) is equivalent to void addLast(E element) method

only difference is

addLast(E element) method implementation:

```
void addLast(E e) {
        Node<E> l = last;
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(l, e, null);
        last = newNode;
        if (l == null)
            first = newNode;
        else
            l.next = newNode;
        size++;
    }
```

And add(E element) method implementation:

```
boolean add(E e) {
        addLast(e);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: As you saw for yourself, it never returns false. You could also read that in the Javadoc of List interface.

Comment: `LinkedList `implements `Collection`, which defines an `add` method that returns a `boolean`, so `LinkedList` needs to implement that method.

Answer (score 4):

Because `java.util.LinkedList` implements the `Collection` interface and the `add()` method in that interface should return true if the collection has changed as a result of the operation. For the linked list, this is always true.

Here is an example in which `add()` returns false:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
System.out.println(set.add(1));
System.out.println(set.add(2));
System.out.println(set.add(1));
```

Outputs:

```
true
true
false
```

The third `add` returns false simply because the set has not changed as a result of the operation (it already contained 1).

Answer (score 2):

It [always](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add(E)) returns true. It must return boolean because interface it implements (`java.util.List`) forces it to return boolean.

```
/**
 * Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
 *
 * <p>This method is equivalent to {@link #addLast}.
 *
 * @param e element to be appended to this list
 * @return {@code true} (as specified by {@link Collection#add})
 */
public boolean add(E e) {
    linkLast(e);
    return true;
}
```

However, `java.util.Set` has different behaviour. It only adds elements if there no elements that are same (according to `Object.equals()`). Just like @jrook mentioned, it will return false in case element you added already exists there.